# Is there a way to maintain map tips and/or actions in an exported PDF using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, actions, maptips

I am working on a project that displays the locations of a group's projects in a city. I have it set up now so that map tips shows the name of the project and location when you hover over the point. I am planning to set up actions so that you can click on the point and it will bring you to a web page with information on that project.

Is there a way to maintain these features in a PDF exported map? If not, what is the point of using these features unless my audience is other GIS users?

I am thinking a workaround might be to include the names of each project in another layer with just the labels and export as a GeoPDF with togglable labels but that is not ideal. And with the actions maybe embed the PDF with hyperlinks after QGIS export. Although, these are not ideal options.

What else can I do?